# Install Apache and PHP on different servers

Tags: php, apache, server

My customer insists on installing Apache-Php-MySQL on 3 different servers. He wants a 3 layer installation for security reasons (Is it 3 layer?).
I know how to install and connect to MySQL on a different machine. But I have no experiences for separating and connecting to PHP of another machine. (some search results suggests PHP-FPM)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you know what i call customers like that? X-Customers.

Comment: @Dagon What do you mean by that? XD

Comment: This is possible with NGINX (If you're client is willing to go for that instead of Apache) by defining a Upstream for PHP. Basically, points to what IP the php-fpm is running on. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/546349/what-is-the-difference-between-using-upstream-and-location-for-php-fpm and http://serverfault.com/questions/383524/nginx-upstream-pass-directly-to-php-fpm-on-another-server

Comment: i wouldn't call this customer 'x-customer'. he is concerned about security. from the security stand point, the less your server does, the less vulnerable it is. if everything is installed on one server, you may run into a problem that if, say, your apache server is compromised, your mysql data can be compromised too. if you have 3 servers (1 for php, 1 for apache, 1 for mysql) you can configure the servers's firewalls to talk through just 1 port for a server, and block all other ports. i believe it's a good reason, and don't think it's too much work actually.